# Top Keyword Not Working in Access 2007

Tags: database, ms-access

```
SELECT top 3 a.[CustID],a.[CustName],a.[ContactNo],a.[Address],[EmailID] ,
       (select count(1) FROM tblCustomer x) as [RecordCount]
FROM tblCustomer a
where a.[CustID] NOT IN (
      SELECT TOP 6 m.[CustID]
      FROM tblCustomer m
      Order by m.[CreatedOn] desc)
order by a.[CreatedOn] desc
```

I m trying to Get top 3 Result from above Query but I m getting a lot more than that:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vUMLBin.jpg]

Can someone Recorrect above query ..

Comment: Could you possibly add a little more verbiage to your description along with some sample data please !

Comment: My Table Data : http://i.imgur.com/dD2jgiG.jpg ... and I m running this Query over this Data "select top 8 CustID,CreatedOn from tblCustomer order by CreatedOn" but I m getting Whole Table as Output instead of top 8 Rows ... .. actually the issue arise b/c  CreatedOn Column containing the Same date .. anyone know how to fix this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOP in Ms Access includes not just the required number, but all matched results. In this case you have chosen date, so if there are several matched dates, they will all be returned. If you need just three records, order by a unique field in addition to the required sort order. For example

```
... order by a.[CreatedOn] desc, custid
```

Comment: Yes, this is even documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195711(v=office.15).aspx)